# What are these IIS7 website bindings? Are they needed? Can I remove them?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, bindings

I notice my main website has these bindings..

```
<binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="808:*" /> 
<binding protocol="net.pipe" bindingInformation="*" /> 
<binding protocol="net.msmq" bindingInformation="localhost" /> 
<binding protocol="msmq.formatname" bindingInformation="localhost" />
```

what are they used for? Can I remove them? How did they get there? I'm sure I've removed them once before... I'm guessing a windows update?

Answer (score 3):

They are used for Windows Communications Foundation (WCF). The preferred Web Services implementation/API for .NET.

> Can I remove them?

Are you *sure* they are not in use? I don't think any infrastructure for Windows Server or common services relies on them (but don't quote me).

Comment: Well .. I've not done any specific WCF programming .. .so I'm assuming they are not getting used. Just a simple FILE -> NEW -> ASP.NET MVC3 webiste (more or less)...